# Spring tool: Exception encountered during context initialization - Unable to start web server; nested exception is

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get a simple Spring Boot to run. It does run and work if in the main I have it set to `HelloWorldRest1Application.class`. Once I change it to HelloWorld I get and can't see it on the localhost.

> 2021-09-19 19:36:40.009  INFO 1664 --- [  restartedMain]
> c.sw409.demo.HelloWorldRest1Application  : Starting
> HelloWorldRest1Application using Java 16.0.1 on DESKTOP-55I895V with
> PID 1664 (C:\Users\ncost\Desktop\Fall 21\Advanced
> Java\java\HelloWorldRest1\target\classes started by ncost in
> C:\Users\ncost\Desktop\Fall 21\Advanced Java\java\HelloWorldRest1)
> 2021-09-19 19:36:40.013  INFO 1664 --- [  restartedMain]
> c.sw409.demo.HelloWorldRest1Application  : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default 2021-09-19 19:36:40.045
> INFO 1664 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults
> active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
> 2021-09-19 19:36:40.160  INFO 1664 --- [  restartedMain]
> c.sw409.demo.HelloWorldRest1Application  : Started
> HelloWorldRest1Application in 0.52 seconds (JVM running for 1.366)

---

Main

```
package com.sw409.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.models.HelloWorldBean;
import com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.services.HelloWorld;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldRest1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
    }

}
```

HelloWorldBean

```
package com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.models;

public class HelloWorldBean {

    String mes;

    public HelloWorldBean(String str) {

        this.mes = str;
    }

    public String getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(String mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return mes;
    }
}
```

HelloWorld

```
package com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.services;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.models.HelloWorldBean;

@RestController
public class HelloWorld {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloworld() {

        return ("hello world");
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public String helloworld(@PathVariable("name") String str) {

        return "hello " + str;
    }

    @GetMapping("/helloworldbean/{name}")
    public HelloWorldBean hello(@PathVariable("name") String str) {
        return new HelloWorldBean("Hello everyone! " + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the the other error i get:                                                                                                                             org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `HelloWorldRest1Application` to package `com.sw409` and set `HelloWorldRest1Application` as your main class as follows:

```kotlin
package com.sw409;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.models.HelloWorldBean;
import com.sw409.HelloWorldRest.services.HelloWorld;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldRest1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldRest1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Comment: the web runs when I have this. But when I try to implement it won't. How do I make these classes work

Comment: "But when I try to implement it won't". What do you mean by this? Have you moved the `HelloWorldRest1Application` to package `com.sw409`?